# How to select the best candidate in a string, using a clue word ahead

Tags: r

I am pondering on how to make a function choose the best candidate using a clue word located ahead. This should opperate in a string set, and I tried to acheive this many times but was not able to do it.

The basic concept is that there is a string like this '----- clueword (candiate1|candidate2...)----' and a function I want can select the most promising candidate depending on a data.

```
clue =  c( 'a',    'to',    'a',   'to',   'to')
word = c('house','school','paper','water','schooling')
cooccur = c(100,    90,      83,    70,     61)
data = data.frame(clue,word,cooccur)
```

Suppose there are two string sets

```
S1 = 'I have a (house|water|paper) and car'
S2 = 'I need to go to (school|schooling) right now'
```

The clue word 'a' has the high frequency of co-occurance with 'house', and 'to' does with 'school'. Thus, using THE function, the outcome should be

```
S1
[1] 'I have a (house) and car'
S2
[2] 'I need to go to (school) right now'
```

You don't need to worry about dealing with removing less promising candidates because this code handles that.

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("\\(([^)]+)", ~paste0("(", paste(THEFUNCTION(unlist(x)), collapse="|")), S1)
```

I know I can use `which.max()` but using it relating to 'clue' is not easy at all. Is there any way letting me get throug this?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
THEFUNCTION <- function(x) { # dummy function, to be replaced by the one that selects w.r.t. co-occurence frequency
  # this function receives inputs without paranthesis: e.g., 'house|water|paper'
  ifelse(grepl('house', x), 'house', 'school')
}

S1 = 'I have a (house|water|paper) and car'
S2 = 'I need to go to (school|schooling) right now'

library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("\\(([^\\)]+)\\)", ~paste0("(", paste(THEFUNCTION(unlist(x)), collapse="|"), ")"), S1)
#[1] "I have a (house) and car"
gsubfn("\\(([^\\)]+)\\)", ~paste0("(", paste(THEFUNCTION(unlist(x)), collapse="|"), ")"), S2)
#[1] "I need to go to (school) right now"
```

Comment: Well, 'data' should play a key role so that there is no problem to function properly,  no matter how many words are contained in the data